# Why can't foo() be called in this script?

Tags: php

[image: code]

I'm sorry this code is only available in a picture, however if need be I'll type it out in text if pictures are not allowed like this.
My question is why can't foo() be called before the "/* now we can safely call foo" comment?

Comment: Please post code as text. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format it properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When a PHP script is being parsed, all top-level functions are defined immediately, and they can be called from anywhere in the script, before or after the definition.

But functions that are defined inside conditional code can't be called until after the conditional is executed, because it doesn't know whether the condition will be true or not when it's parsing the script.